# How can I use third party dependencies in custom task under buildSrc in Gradle

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I have followed this guide for creating a custom task with Gradle.
http://www.ysofters.com/2015/02/26/how-to-create-gradle-project-with-custom-task-classes-in-groovy/
I also had a look at the gradle doc. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html

It's very clear, and I can get the examples to compile and use the tasks, so everythings fine so far.

However, examples only show the import of gradle api-files, i.e.

```
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction
```

I want to add some more dependencies i.e

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource
```

but I can do that - gradle will complain and say "unable to resolve class .."

I tried to also set up spring-core and apache-commons under the buildscript->dependencies closure in build.gradle but it didn't make any difference i.e.

```
buildscript {
 dependencies {

        classpath group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: springVersion
        classpath group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.4'
      .....
```

So, what am I missing - how can I use third party dependencies in my custom task class?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you need to put a build.gradle file into your `buildSrc` directory. You can checkout the `buildSrc/build.gradle` file from the gradle project itself as an example: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v4.1.0/buildSrc/build.gradle

Comment: Thanks for that. Works great.

Comment: link is broken :(

Comment: buildSrc/build.gradle worked for me as well. I added my repositories and dependencies outside buildscript (no buildscript section)

Comment: fixed the link. sorry for the delay